# How to skip symlinks when using git stash

Tags: git

Here is my use case:
I am working on a deployment script that looks something like this:

```
cd /project-deployment-dir
git stash --include-untracked
git pull
git stash pop
```

It would work fine if not for the fact that I have some files in repository replaced with symlinks. eg.

```
var/storage => /nfs/project-1/storage
var/cache => /tmpfs/project-1/cache
```

while this is in the repository:

```
var/storage/images/.gitkeep
var/storage/documents/.gitkeep
```

Is there a way to tell `git stash` and `git pull` to skip certain folder and leave it unchanged.
Or even better, to skip all symlinks and keep them unchanged?

edit:
The first stash command gives me following error:

```
error: 'var/storage/documents/.gitkeep' is beyond a symbolic link
fatal: Unable to process path var/storage/documents/.gitkeep
Cannot save the current worktree state
```

edit2:
I also tried to use `git pathspec` but the effect is also incorrect, in fact its very weird and I don't even understand why this is happening:

```
$ git status
On branch release/4.23.0
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/release/4.23.0'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    deleted:    var/storage/order-documents/.gitkeep
    deleted:    var/storage/printer-files/.gitkeep

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .updating

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")


$ git stash push --include-untracked -- ':(exclude)var/storage'
Saved working directory and index state WIP on 4.23.0: ccd3357 Update composer.lock
fatal: empty string is not a valid pathspec. please use . instead if you meant to match all paths


$ git stash push --include-untracked -- . ':(exclude)var/storage'
Saved working directory and index state WIP on 4.23.0: ccd3357 Update composer.lock
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
var
hint: Use -f if you really want to add them.
hint: Turn this message off by running
hint: "git config advice.addIgnoredFile false"


$ git status
On branch release/4.23.0
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/release/4.23.0'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   .updating

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    deleted:    var/storage/order-documents/.gitkeep
    deleted:    var/storage/printer-files/.gitkeep


$ git version
git version 2.34.1
```

Instead of being stashed my files (in this case just `.updating`) got staged. Also I had to provide the positive pathspec even though apparently its no longer required since git v2.12.

Comment: https://diegocandal.com/2020/02/05/how-to-git-ignore-symlinks-of-a-project/ & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650871/telling-git-to-ignore-symlinks

Comment: I don't think .gitignore is a solution since those files are already in the repository and I want them to stay there. I just don't want them to be updated on my current machine.

Answer (score 0):

From
[Useful Git Commands](https://www.ecenica.com/support/answer/git-commands/) :

**Ignore symlinks**

Add all symbolic links to your `.gitignore` :

```
find . -type l >> .gitignore
```

**Remove all symbolic links from repository**

```
find . -type l -exec git rm --cached {} \;
```

Other useful commands can also be found in this link.

Comment: It does not work, because symlinks re not in the repo, they are on the server replacing content that is in the repo